# How to attach fingerprint reader in my vb.net project?

Tags: vb.net

i'm making a attendance system using a fingerprint device to login/logout..my problem is i dont know how to attach the device to my project..my device is U.are.U 4500 DIGITAL PERSONA FingerPrint Reader.. i dont have any SDK of it..or a CD..

i downloaded a software from this site:
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=ob-72127-1
and after i install it..i find that the device is working well..

my only problem is i dont know how to attach it to my project..

tnx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I used the same fingerprint scanner before and all you have to do is use the supplied SDK. Add a reference to the DLL required to operate the hardware. I used Griaule Biometrics SDK, a 3rd party SDK for the same hardware. The official SDK should be the same.

Right click on project.
Select Properties.
Click on the Reference Tab.